# Cannot find type 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in-app purchases for my app.

```
import StoreKit
import UIKit

class BuyStoreViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
//code
}
```

However, It keeps giving me the errors "Cannot find type 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver' in scope" and "Cannot find type 'SKProductsRequestDelegate' in scope". I think it has something to do with the implementation of StoreKit, but I am not sure. Additionally, the "SKProductsRequestDelegate" and "SKPaymentTransactionObserver" are greyed out (it does not turn purple like the "UIViewController" does). Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce. You may need to slap Xcode on the side of the head by deleting the derived data or something.

Comment: Do you have paid Apple Developer program? If you are using free Apple Developr account, storeKit will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I just had to move all my files to a new project, that worked for me.